# Did Chrome 56 stop to support "wildcard" cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

As of version **56** Chrome does not accept cookies in my setup. The setup is

- https://login-with.now.sh is the "app"
- https://login.now.sh is a authentication microservice which (on success) sets two cookies ("jwt" and "profile"). The Cookie Domain is set to "now.sh"

However, the cookies are visible in the response header (dev tools) but they don't appear back in the login-with.now.sh "app".

This did work with Chrome **55**

It is still working with Safari, Firefox and Edge.

Is something wrong with my cookies or what is the matter here?

[image]

Comment: To reproduce, just open dev tool network details and login in on the website https://login-with.now.sh (TRY button).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chrome which is filed in the [Chrome bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=692655).